# C# Target="_blank" in a LinkButton

Tags: c#, target, linkbutton

is it possible to have a `target="_blank"` in `LinkButton`...mine doesnt seem to be working

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="g31" Text="PDF" 
    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"productID") %>'
    CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"documentID") %>'
    OnCommand="linkbutton_showpdf" target="_blank">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Or would I have to use a different button format?

Comment: I have a Response.Redirect in my code behind...I am trying to open it in another window.

Comment: I might be missing it, but I don't see any sign of `target="_blank"`.

Comment: You may get the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab

Comment: The `LinkButton` acts like a `Button` control. Would you expect it to be able to facilitate this behavior? If it is absolutely necessary either use javascript or a hyperlink.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just render an anchor with href set to appropriate url and set the `target` attribute to `_blank` it will open the url into new window.

```
<a href="urlOfThePage" target="_blank" >Click me</a>
```

Comment: This is not correct for asp.net. See my answer below.

Answer (score 36):

You can use like this with Link Button

Replace `target="_blank"` to `OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';"`.

Comment: I made a mistake... it's `w` and not `W`. Thank you. It's working now

Comment: This will make every link within that form "target=_blank"  after the linkbutton is clicked

Comment: you need to add 
`setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);`

Answer (score 22):

None of the current answers are correct, even the `<a>` tag is not the correct answer in asp.net.

Use the HyperLink Button. There is even a property for the target attribute.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='http://rrs.com/aspx/Equipment/EquipmentType.aspx'
    Target="_blank">
        Create/Edit Part Types
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Hyperlink control, which does have a `target='_blank'` property. However if you must use a LinkButton control, then you can add a `OnClientClick` attribute which then calls a JavaScript function to open a popup window

```
window.open();
```

Answer (score 5):

I was working with Devsaninii's answer where I changed the target of the form and found the undesired behavior of the rest of my pages switching to a new window after clicking a link that changed the target. Which made sense but was undesirable.

I was opening files with some links and loading new pages with others. I wanted the files to open in new windows and I wanted the new pages to open in the same window. But after I changed the target everything was in a new window. I could have gone through and added a client click handler to each and every `linkbutton`, but that was too cumbersome.

So here is what I came up with:

I added a class to my `linkbuttons` that were supposed to have a new window as the target and then I added this little piece of jQuery to my script:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('changeTarget')) {
            window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
        } else {
            window.document.forms[0].target = '_self';
        }
    });
});
```

Now when a `linkbutton` that should have a new window is pressed, it opens in a new window, and when anything else is pressed, it opens in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

A LinkButton in ASP.NET web forms just submits the underlying form using JavaScript so the target="_blank" doesn't actually do anything. To open a new window you can instead modify the target property of the "form" via JavaScript using the LinkButton's OnClientClick event. You also need to undo the modification after the click (using a setTimeout) otherwise further button clicks will unintentionally target a new tab.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="uiNewTabExample" Text="Open New Tab" OnClick="uiNewTabExample_Click" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = '' }, 0);" 
runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"` instead.

```html
<asp:LinkButton 
        ID="btNext" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="btn btn-sm default next"
        OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" 
        OnClick="ibtNext_Click">
        Next
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

After looking at these answers and none was exactly what I wanted (do this with a button look), I ended up using a hyperlink control, but used the same css style as my regular buttons:

```
.button {

    background-color:#011745;
    color:white;
    padding:7px 12px 7px 12px;
    margin:3px;
    border-style:none;
    font-size:12px;

}

.button:hover {

    background-color:#336699;
    color:white;
    padding:7px 12px 7px 12px;
    margin:3px;
    border-style:none;
    font-size:12px;

}
```

It looked just like them!  If you are going for a button that opens a link in a new window, which I was, it was almost perfect.  In a set of table cells, it displayed just a touch lower than the regular buttons, so I styled it like this: "position:relative; top:-2px;" and that did the trick.  I also had to force the forecolor white:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="btnSummaryReport" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text="SUMMARY REPORT" CssClass="button" ForeColor="white" Font-Size="8" style="position:relative; top:-2px" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to @Devsainii answer above.

Add the attribute `OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';"` to your LinkButton and then in the code behind, just use `Response.Redirect("~/AnotherPage.aspx")` to navigate to another page.