# How to display pdf file in a seperate tab in a browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, asplinkbutton

I have tried a code to open a pdf file in a web browser. It give to allows me to open the file through pdf reader no in the browser. Almost all the codes i found over the internet are also same as this code. But this code doesn't work as i expected.

Help me to figure out the problem in here. I'm using a link button in the aspx.

Here is my code

aspx code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="pdfViewLOP" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 10px" OnClick="pdfViewLOP_Click" >View PDF</asp:LinkButton>
```

aspx.cs

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "viewPDF.aspx"));
```

Code of the new page which pdf should be displayed

```
string name=Session["name"].ToString();
int refNo = Convert.ToInt32(name);
string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/filesPDF/" + refNo + ".pdf");
WebClient User = new WebClient();
Byte[] buffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);

if (buffer != null)
{
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
     Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Just add a `target="_blank" ` attribute to your link to open it in a new window. You *can't* control how each browser or user treats new windows - what you see as tabs are actually new windows

Comment: Which link? Im using a link button and i have added it in the link button

Comment: A linkbutton is an `<a>` link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Target="\_blank" in a LinkButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255427/c-sharp-target-blank-in-a-linkbutton)

Answer (score -1):

How if you directly create a hyperlink with target _blank and path of file as a href of hyperlink.

So the result hyperlink generated inside the html page is

```
<a href="link_to_pdf" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

Comment: Can't you suggest me a way to do it as i have done already? Because this code works  but not in mine. I may have done a mistake. But i can't find it

Comment: Hi mate i don't know asp but i certainly know if your code is generating this html tag it will work perfectly. You will not need to change much code you just need to remove some unnecessary code.

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)