# Server code with _blank target

Tags: .net, hyperlink

App is .Net. I want to record clicks on a hyperlink.  Easy enough.  I changed it to a link button and can now execute the required server-side code to record the click.  Problem is: Now I can't launch the link to a _blank target. I want to eat my cake and have it too.  Server-side code and a _blank target.  How do?

Comment: Check this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab

Comment: protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Your existing code to record the click ...
            // ...
            // ...


            // Generate client-side code to open the link in a new window
            // (this assumes that you have stored the URL in a string variable
            //  named targetURL)
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                "openLinkInNewWindow",
                "window.open('" + targetURL + "', '_blank');", true);

Comment: That last coment worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: "Post the code" means "edit your question and post the code there", not "post the code in a comment".

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Type, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

Eg.:

```
// Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
String csname1 = "PopupScript";
Type cstype = this.GetType();
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript>window.open(url, '_blank') </");
cstext1.Append("script>");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
```