# How Link button perform new tab when clicked even it has also jquery code to perform

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible that a link button can open a tab window with a certain URL even it has also jquery code to perform like showing a popup box?

Let say when I click the link button, it popup messagebox came from jquery code and also open a new tab. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery deals with client side
LinkButton is a server side control

Check following STO thread:
[Link Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab)

Also, opening a new tab can be handled by browsers, so some browser may open
a new tab while others may open a new window