# How to enable right click "open tab" in ASP:LinkButton inside of UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a LinkButton inside of an UpdatePanel.  Hovering over the link the browser shows that the link points to "DoPostback ( ...  ) ", because it is ajax-y the browser disables the right-click "open in new tab" option.  How can I make the link normal even when it lives inside of an updatepanel?

Comment: LinkButton is designed to do a postback and work like a button. So you need to look at HyperLink control instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [link button property to open in new tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab)