# Why using IHttpHandler causes my submit button to open to the new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnValidateName">
    <div class="spPad">
        <b class="userLabel">Enter Full/Partial First or Last Name to Search (Leave blank for all):</b>
    </div>
    <div class="spPad" style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width="95%" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="spPad" style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnValidateName" CssClass="orange button" runat="server" Text="Validate Name" onclick="btnValidateName_Click" />
    </div>
    <div class="spPad" style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblIsValid"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

After searching and displaying the result inside a repeater, I allow user to view the file in the browser by opening a new window by clicking on a linkbutton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />
```

The code behind is this:

```
protected void ViewFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("OpenFilePDF.ashx?fileVar=" + Session["fileName"]);
}
```

The `OpenFilePDF.ashx` code is:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    System.Web.HttpRequest request2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
    string strSessVar2 = request2.QueryString["fileVar"];

    try
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        byte[] fileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"C:\PDF", strSessVar2));
        response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", String.Format("inline; filename={0}", strSessVar2));
        response.BinaryWrite(fileByteArray);
        response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ce)
    {

    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The scenario that is happening is, after the search and displaying the result, if the user clicks on the `View in Browser` button and comes back to the old window and clicks on the `Validate Name` button the result goes in the window that was originally opened by clicking on `View in Browser` button instead of running the search on the current window. I have to refresh the page for it to search on the current window again, even if the new window was already opened.

How do I resolve the issue I am having?

Answer (score 2):

Your `View in Browser` is implemented as

`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />`

On the client click, the form element of your web page will look like

`<form ... target="_blank">`

Causing any submit of the form to open in a new window. However, every single postback to ASP.NET constitutes a submission of your form, so everything will open in a new window. Rather than setting the `target` attribute on the form, you might consider setting the attribute just on the link. To do that, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637208/1981387

Keep in mind, you will have to use a `HyperLink` instead of a `LinkButton`. Actually, this will benefit you by reducing the round trip back to your server by 1, because you are using the `LinkButton` to redirect to another url anyways. So your `HyperLink` can just have an `href` that points to `"OpenFilePDF.ashx?fileVar=" + Session["fileName"]` to begin with.

**Edit/TL;DR:**

Change

`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />`

To

code-behind:

```
public string FileLocation
{   
   get
   {
      return "OpenFilePDF.ashx?fileVar=" + Session["fileName"];
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
lnkViewProper.NavigateUrl = FileLocation;
...
}
```

markup:

`<asp:HyperLink 
   ID="lnkViewProper" 
   Text="View in Browser" 
   runat="server" 
   Target="_blank" />`

Comment: I changed the default event to false so it's a button instead of "submit" but it was doing the same thing. I am guessing it's because of the OnClientClick method.

Comment: I can't use `Session["fileName"]` from a Hyperlink because it is not in code behind. How do I access that?