# Set Image Button Control target

Tags: jquery, vb.net

i have an Image Button Control:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" ImageAlign="Middle"  ImageUrl="~/img/search-butt.png" />
```

and the behind code of this control is:

```
 Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/search?q='" + TextBox1.Text + "'&sitesearch=http://example.com")
```

well, i need this (google page) open in a new tab not current tab. how can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab

Comment: didn't work for image button.