# Using LinkButton PostbackUrl - new window/tab needed to open

Tags: asp.net, http, webforms, postback

Im posting and redirecting to a third party by setting the PostBackUrl property on a LinkButton.

My problem is that I want this to open in a new tab but target="_blank" doesnt do anything here.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hlApplication" runat="server" Text="Start your application" aria-describedby="information" target="_blank" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>

hlApplication.PostbackUrl ="http://externalurl";
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='http://www.google.com' Target="_blank">Google </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: @SteveWard check this [link](http://%20http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, we had to have a hyperlink that opened a new tab that contained the form. This form is automaticaly posted by Javascript and the user taken to their destination. This was the only way we could get this to work