# asp.net linkbutton in updatepanel, open new window

Tags: asp.net

I have a linkbutton inside an updatepanel. When I click this linkbutton, I'd like it to "post" in a new window (target=_blank). now , this can be easily done by setting form target, but ajaxpostback doesn't use form post. any workaround? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab This may help you.

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried ?